# Razor Pages - Model validation fails due to multiple objects sharing parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I am running into an issue that I cannot seem to wrap my head around. I am using Razor Pages and have two objects that can be bound.

```
[BindProperty]
public MeetingMinuteInputDto MeetingToCreate { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public MeetingMinuteUpdateDto MeetingToUpdate { get; set; }
```

Above two are separate dto for creating/updating a base entity in my database. I have two separate dto because I allow only specific items for update (to prevent overposting). Both classes have a `Name`, `Date`, and `Reminder`. The `MeetingMinuteUpdateDto` only allows the `Date` to be changed.

The **Name** property is required and cannot be null. The reason I have both objects in the same page/controller is because I am using modals to create/update and I would rather not create multiple pages just to create/edit objects.

I have two forms that users can fill out - one for editing and one for creating. Each one binds the values to a specific object (i.e. the create form will bind its posted form values to the `MeetingMinuteInputDto`).

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
          <label asp-for="MeetingToCreate.Name" class="control-label"></label>
          <input asp-for="MeetingToCreate.Name" class="form-control" />
          <span asp-validation-for="MeetingToCreate.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>
</div>
```

Above is a sample of my form for the creating a new meeting. I checked to see that when the form is submitted, only the `MeetingMinuteInputDto` value is being bound to. The other object (`MeetingMinuteUpdateDto`) has null values for all its properties.

But when I check the model state, MVC throws an error on the "Name" property saying that it is null. I looked at the results of the model state and there is a key named "Name" which is not tied to any object that fails validation.

If I remove the other object (i.e. I remove `MeetingMinuteUpdateDto`) from the page and do model binding, everything works correctly. How do I prevent the model validation from trying to validate an objects that is not relevant for the current action? I want the Create action to only validate the create object and vice versa.

I tried doing `TryValidateModel(MeetingToCreate)` but that also provides a false for model validation.

[image]

**Note**: I can't just place the object properties outside as I have other pages where I need to do this in which the update/create objects have 10+ properties that are shared/not shared.

---

**Update** - I can manually remove the validation error from the model state dictionary. But I don't really like that approach as I don't want to have to iterate through all the properties for the incorrect keys and remove them.

---

**Update 2**: Here is more detail on when this issue is occurring:

```
public class MeetingMinuteInputDto: MeetingMinuteManipulationDto
    {
        public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
    }

public class MeetingMinuteUpdateDto : MeetingMinuteManipulationDto
    {
    }

public class MeetingMinuteManipulationDto
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IFormFile FileToUpload { get; set; }
    }
```

In my Razor Page, I have both of these properties with the bind property attribute:

```
public class MeetingMinutesModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public MeetingMinuteInputDto MeetingToCreate { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public MeetingMinuteUpdateDto MeetingToUpdate { get; set; } 
        //...stuff
}
```

My form on the create/edit page looks as such:

```
<form asp-page="/MeetingMinute/MeetingMinutes" asp-page-handler="CreateMeeting">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
              <label asp-for="MeetingToCreate.Name" class="control-label"></label>
              <input asp-for="MeetingToCreate.Name" class="form-control" />
              <span asp-validation-for="MeetingToCreate.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
          </div>
    </div>
    //other inputs and label for rest of the properties
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The input for the form is set to bind specifically to the **MeetingToCreate** property. When I submit the form, the form values are correctly bound. But at the same time, I am getting ModelState errors for the `MeetingToUpdate` property (as it shares some fields with `MeetingToCreate`).

I am assuming that in a Razor Page, model state validation is validating the **MeetingMinutesModel** and not the individual `MeetingToCreate/MeetingToUpdate` properties. In MVC, I assume this might be different as actions need to have parameters as opposed to open-ended properties on the page model in razor pages.

Comment: Rather than add these as properties to the PageModel, make them parameters to your Create and Update action methods.

Comment: @MikeBrind I need to have them as public parameters as I need access to them in my razor view. As the razor view only accepts the razor page model as the model, how would I go about accessing those values in the view if they are action level parameters?

Comment: Could you share the more relevant code that can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @XueliChen Please see my latest update for more details

Comment: @Help123 were you able to solve this issue? I'm also facing this problem, two objects are related and share the same parameter name. I want to insert both objects on the same page but the model is Invalid.

Comment: @DC_AC Didn't find any solution that allowed me to utilize models with shared property names. I opted to create a class that had the shared property names so that it could be used for both objects depending on the page action being called. I believe that the entire page itself is the "model" that is being validated as opposed to individual properties but I'd have to dig into the source code to confirm that.

Answer (score 5):

I was doing something similar. Searching for any solution, I find your question, but not a solution I share the solution.

I implement multiple BindProperty and multiple Actions OnPost, 
and the solution I find is to do some in the Asp.Net MVC, using the [Bind] property.

In your case, it would be.

```
public class MeetingMinutesModel : PageModel
{
    //[BindProperty] remove it
    public MeetingMinuteInputDto MeetingToCreate { get; set; }

    //[BindProperty] remove it
    public MeetingMinuteUpdateDto MeetingToUpdate { get; set; }
    //...stuff
}

public IActionResult OnPost([Bind("Name, FileToUpload, AdditionalInfo")] MeetingMinuteInputDto MeetingToCreate)
{
    //Do somthing
}
```

Comment: Great solution!

Definitely a work around. It's not ideal to declare the same identifier as a property of the PageModel and a parameter of the page handler. (Also, to have a property of the PageModel who is only there to 'trick' AspNetCore)

Still though, it's the best solution I've found to this problem. Does exactly what I want - well done!

Answer (score 1):

In Razor pages , @model in the page is **PageModel** and the **"Name"** property of `MeetingMinuteManipulationDto` class is `Required` , so model state validation validates all the properties in the PageModel .
If you insist on the original idea , you could try to use [ViewComponent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to implement create/edit objects in the same razor view.

Comment: Hi Xueli, I figured that might be the case. What do you mean by using view component to create/edit objects? I can certainly put a form into a view component and show in on the razor view - but when I post the form - it will end up going to the razor page and have the same model binding problem. How would view components help in this case?